# Как правильно произвести умножение значений input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть ползунок. Логика ползунка простая. Нужно чтобы при увеличение value на 10, нижние 4 значения умножались на 10.
Сейчас часть цикла работает и часть умножается, а всё остальное нет.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить эту проблему?

```js
$.fn.digits = function(){ 
  return this.each(function(){ 
    $(this).text( $(this).text().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g)); 
  })
}

function isNumber (o) {
  return ! isNaN (o-0);
}  


$('input[type=range]').on('input', function () {


  var energyBill = $('#energyBill').val();

  
  $('#range-value').text(energyBill);

  var energySavings = (energyBill * 10);
  var energySavingsYearly = (energySavings * 10);

  $('#savingsMonthly').text(energySavings);
  $('#savingsYearly').text(energySavingsYearly);
  
  $('#range-value').digits();
  $('#savingsMonthly').digits();
  $('#savingsYearly').digits();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="savings-calculator">
  <div class="range-slider">
    <input type="range" id="energyBill" name="energyBill" min="20" max="700" value="20" step="10">
    <strong><span id="range-value">20</span>$</strong>
   
  </div>
  <span id="savingsCoins" class="two-digits">0.003$</span> 
  <span id="savingsYearly" class="two-digits">143.349.555.140 </span>
 <span id="savingsMonthly" class="two-digits">20</span></p>
<span id="savingsGains" class="two-digits">13.048</span>
  <a class="btn" href="www.yandex.ru">перейти</a>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в регулярке, что бы она там не делала

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: Что это `143.349.555.140` за число?

Comment: @nazarpunk это рандомное число.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить эту проблему. куда мне стоит копать?

Comment: "это рандомное число. " и каким образом его к Number приводить?